# how to adjust the space using auto layouts?

Tags: ios, autolayout, xcode5.1

I am new to auto layout, I am using auto layout in my project. By using auto layout I cannot adjust the space between each element. Please look at my xib. I have designed a screen in 3.5 inch screen but auto layout are not adjust in 4 inch screen.
 [image]

[image]

I have gone through the raywenderlich site for auto layout. I could not find the space adjustment for elements. Can any one please tell me how to adjust the spaces by using auto layout.

I have one more doubt when i am drag and drop the elements unable to get the constraints. Is i need to change any settings. By default auto layout option is enabled but still i am not getting the constraints.

Comment: Are you sure yo do not have auto layout warning in IB? Frame and constraints may not satisfy each other or there may be ambiguities.?

Comment: @MertBuran, ya there are no warnings and errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multipliers to do that. Create an equal heights constraint between one of your view and superview and set multiplier 0.5 (or 2). Now height of it will be proportional to the superview and spaces will be adjusted.

Hope that helps.